# Is it possible to keep reloading with flask even though I have syntax errors

Tags: flask, development-environment

Flask's autoreloader is very nice, however I often make syntax mistakes, which causes the reloader to crash.

Is it possible to make the reloader catch the syntax error and still print it, but keep on reloading when the offending file changes again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Flask-Failsafe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Failsafe/), here's [a bit more](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2012/9/15/avoid-reloader-crashes-with-flask-failsafe/) from the author.

Answer (score 1):

The 2021 answer to this question is to run your app with `flask run`. You probably want to set `FLASK_ENV=development` in the environment too. The Flask runner will wrap your code in a safe loader that handles syntax errors when loading your Python code.

Note that in Flask 2.0.1 (the latest release at the moment) there's a [bug](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4169) where syntax errors in your code will be replaced by a strange TypeError. That bug was fixed at the end of June 2021 but that version has not yet shipped. The error report is not great but Flask will reload once you fix your syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using an [Application Factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory).  In my `__init__.py` in my application package, rather than

```
from flask import Flask
flaskapp = Flask(__name__)
```

and having the flask application be global, update to:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    flaskapp = Flask(__name__)
    return flaskapp
```

Flask can now continue picking up changes and restart the app after a syntax error